# Identify the tuple in the list of tuples if the tuple contains substring

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
l1 = [('is', 'VBZ'), ('plant', 'NN')]
```

I want to check if the `VB` in present in the list

I have used the following code but it is not giving me the result.

```
match = [x for x in l1 if 'VB' in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
l1 = [('is', 'VBZ'), ('plant', 'NN')]

print([x for x in l1 if 'VB' in x[1]])
```

Output

```
[('is', 'VBZ')]
```

**Why your code is not working**

You are checking if `VB` is in `('is', 'VBZ')` and it is not. As I understand those are `POS tags` and will always be at 1st index. You need to check if `VB` is present at index 1 of each tuple in the list

Comment: i have changed the description.

Comment: @userD1989 how does it change your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

In your solution you want to check for substring, for that you will need to search through the elements in **Tuple**.

If you want to search exact string then your solution is right

```
'VBZ' in ('is', 'VBZ')
==> True

'VB' in ('is', 'VBZ')
==> False
```

if you know exatly 2 elements 
 will be in tuple

```
[tu for tu in l1 if 'VB' in (tu[1] or tu[0])] 

==> [('is', 'VBZ')]
```

if you are not sure of the elements in tuple

```
[tu for tu in l1 if any(['VB' in elem for elem in tu])] 
==> [('is', 'VBZ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not have 'VB' occurring always on 1st index,

```
match = [y for y in l1 if any(['VB' in x for x in y])]
```

step 1 : Visit a tuple one by one.

step 2 : Check if string 'VB' exists in any of the string-items of the visited tuple.